# generate vector lines of planting from a raster uav image

Tags: qgis, rgb

I have a high quality drone image and I want to generate the planting line from raster. I will transform rgb to false ndvi or others index. The vector lines must  go through the green areas of the raster (picture)

[image]

Is there a plugin or a combination of them to allows me to do it?

Comment: Do you want to make line segments broken where there's a gap in the green of a single line? Or do you want to make lines that follow the whole underlying line even if there's breaks in the green (like in the one that's almost on the lower left-upper right diagonal)?

Comment: Thanks for your quickly answer. I did a new print screen with a better explanation to your question because i do not known how put an image in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In broad strokes, you can reclassify your raster, then run a thinning algorithm to generalize the centerline of your rows (again, as raster cells), and finally convert those to poly line vector file.  This approach requires GRASS plugin with QGIS.

From the geoprocessing toolbox, you can put an NDVI raster through these steps:

- r.reclassify - set your green area to 1, all other values to null
- r.thin - set your minimum distance to the cell size for your raster
- r.to.vect - set your output type to line, and designate your 1 value for conversion

Answer (score 0):

I wish to generate continuous lines, allowing adjacent segments to join in a single line like I show in the picture:
[image]